# How to use timestamp/rowversion data types in Visio?

Tags: datatypes, database-diagrams, visio

I am using Visio 2010 to create a ER diagram. When I insert the column names, I can't find `timestamp` or `rowversion` data types.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: You can use Small Time Stamp (auto)

Comment: @aasim.abdullah I also don't have Small Time Stamp ??

Comment: Strange, as i can see/use it on Visio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Small Time Stamp (auto)

[image: Visio2010]